# Can't find a means of paying form 8879, Online options are broken

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

My girlfriend is an Au Pair from Brazil who is trying to pay the taxes she owes as part of her form 8879. She payed H&R Block expat tax services to file for her. When her return was accepted, they sent her a list of online services that allow you to pay your taxes online ([www.payUSAtax.com](http://www.payUSAtax.com), fed.acipayonline.com, or [www.PAY1040.com](http://www.PAY1040.com)). None of them present an option to pay a form 8879. We then called H&R Block, who directed us to ID.me. The ID.me site was completely non-functional on a phone (wouldn't accept an identity verification image). On a laptop it would upload the image but claimed it didn't have a face in it (it's a standard Virginia drivers license and the face was very visible). We tried several variations of the photo, all of which were refused by the system.

Finally, we called the IRS at 800-829-1040. After trying several options we found that there was no option we could press that actually presented us with an opportunity to pay or a way to talk to an actual person. At this point I don't know how to pay. I can't understand why this is so hard. We've tried 5 different systems now. When we asked her Au Pair friends how they did it, they all just said they didn't pay.

We are trying to use EFTPS now, but it said it's going to take 7 days to physically mail us a pin number. I'm expecting this process to fail somehow, because nothing related to the government ever works in my experience. In the meantime, does anyone know of a reasonable way that we can get this tax bill payed?

Answer (score 1):

Form 8879 is a signature authorization to e-file the tax return in her name. She signed it so H&R Block could e-file the tax return they prepared. The amounts there taken from her form 1040 and are there for her to perform a check and make sure that she's authorizing filing the correct return.

When submitting payment, you're paying for her tax return (form 1040), **not** the e-file signature page (form 8879).

You could also provide the banking information on the form 1040 itself for the IRS to do direct debit, but if you already filed then it's too late.